# CMutablePointer<NSRange> dead end

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, swift

I'm trying to call lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex method of NSLayoutManager object in Swift. Its description is that:

```
func lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(glyphIndex: Int, effectiveRange: CMutablePointer<NSRange>)
```

But I can't figure it out how am I suppose to call it. According to Apple docs I have to call it like this:

```
let someRange : NSRange = ...
layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(0, effectiveRange: &someRange)
```

That's what documentation says. But I get an error: 'NSRange' is not a subtype of '@lvalue $T5'

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making it a `var` instead of a `let`:

```
var someRange: NSRange = ...
layoutManager.lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex(0, effectiveRange: &someRange)
```

Basically: using the `&` on a `var` gives you something compatible with a `CMutablePointer`, but a `let` is not supposed to be mutable. Hence the type error.

If you want to pass a null pointer, just write `nil` instead of `&someRange` (and then of course you don't need to declare the extra `var`).

Comment: How do I pass a nil Range to "lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex"?

"var someRange: NSRange?" 

doesn't work and I get the Error "Could not find an overload for 'lineFragmentRectForGlyphAtIndex' that accepts the supplied arguments"